# Updating spacy.tokenizer._get_regex_pattern(nlp.tokenizer.token_match) so that hashtags are tokenized as a single token

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, tokenize, hashtag

This is my first time using spacy and I am trying to learn how to edit the tokenizer on one of the pretrained models (en_core_web_md) so that when tweets are tokenized, the entire hashtag becomes a single token (e.g. I want one token '#hashtagText', the default would be two tokens, '#' and 'hashtagText').

I know I am not the first person that has faced this issue. I have tried implementing the advice other places online but after using their methods the output remains the same (#hashtagText is two tokens). These articles show the methods I have tried.

https://the-fintech-guy.medium.com/spacy-handling-of-hashtags-and-dollartags-ed1e661f203c

https://towardsdatascience.com/pre-processing-should-extract-context-specific-features-4d01f6669a7e

---

Shown in the code below, my troubleshooting steps have been:

1. save the default pattern matching regex (default_token_matching_regex)
2. save the regex that nlp (the pretrained model) is using before any updates (nlp_token_matching_regex_pre_update)

Note: I originally suspected these would be the same, but they are not. See below for outputs.

3. Append the regex I need (#\w+) to the list that nlp is current using, save this combination as updated_token_matching_regex
4. Update the regex nlp is using with the variable created above (updated_token_matching_regex)
5. Save the new regex used by nlp to verify things were updated correctly (nlp_token_matching_regex_post_update).

See code below:

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_md
import re

nlp = en_core_web_md.load()

# Spacys default token matching regex.
default_token_matching_regex = spacy.tokenizer._get_regex_pattern(nlp.Defaults.token_match)

# Verify what regex nlp is using before changing anything.
nlp_token_matching_regex_pre_update = spacy.tokenizer._get_regex_pattern(nlp.tokenizer.token_match)

# Create a new regex that combines the default regex and a term to treat hashtags as a single token. 
updated_token_matching_regex = f"({nlp_token_matching_regex_pre_update}|#\w+)"

# Update the token matching regex used by nlp with the regex created in the line above.
nlp.tokenizer.token_match = re.compile(updated_token_matching_regex).match

# Verify that nlp is now using the updated regex.
nlp_token_matching_regex_post_update = spacy.tokenizer._get_regex_pattern(nlp.tokenizer.token_match)

# Now let's try again
s = "2020 can't get any worse #ihate2020 @bestfriend <https://t.co>"
doc = nlp(s)

# Let's look at the lemmas and is stopword of each token
print(f"Token\t\tLemma\t\tStopword")
print("="*40)
for token in doc:
    print(f"{token}\t\t{token.lemma_}\t\t{token.is_stop}")
```

[image: Output of print statements:]

As you can see above, the tokenization behavior is not as it should be with the addition of '#\w+'. See below for printouts of all the troubleshooting variables.

[image: default_token_matching_regex - Default regex, not used by my nlp]

[image: nlp_token_matching_regex_pre_update - Regex used by my nlp before I change anything.]

[image: updated_token_matching_regex - Shows the regex I will use to overwrite nlps regex with]

[image: nlp_token_matching_regex_post_update - shows the regex nlp uses was successfully updated.]

Since I feel like I have proven to myself above that I did correctly update the regex nlp is using, the only possible issue I could think of is that the regex itself was wrong. I tested the regex by itself and it seems to behave as intended, see below:

[image: testing regex to pull out #hashTagText as a single token.]

Is anyone able to see the error that is causing nlp to tokenize #hashTagText as two tokens after its nlp.tokenizer.token_match regex was updated to do it as a single token?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it is the best possible solution, but I did find a way to make it work. See below for what I did:

Spacy gives us the chart below which shows the order things are processed when tokenization is performed.

[image: Tokenization steps]

I was able to use the tokenizer.explain() method to see that the hashtags were being ripped off due to a prefix rule. Viewing the tokenizer.explain() output is a simple as running the code below, where "first_tweet" is any string.

```
tweet_doc = nlp.tokenizer.explain(first_tweet)
for token in tweet_doc: 
  print(token)
```

Next, referencing the chart above, we see that prefix rules are the first things applied during the tokenization process.

This meant that even though I updated the token_match rules with a regular expression that allows for keeping "#Text" as a single token, it didn't matter because by the time the token_match rules were evaluated the prefix rule had already separated the '#' from the text.

Since this is a twitter project, I will never want "#" treated as a prefix. Therefore my solution was to remove "#" from the list of prefixes considered, this was accomplished with the code below:

```
default_prefixes = list(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
default_prefixes.remove('#')
prefix_regex = spacy.util.compile_prefix_regex(default_prefixes)
nlp.tokenizer.prefix_search = prefix_regex.search
```

and that's it! Hope this solution helps someone else.

Final thoughts:

Recently spacy was updated to version 3.0. I am curious if prior versions of the spacy pretrained models did not include '#' in the prefix list. That is the only explanation I can come up with for why the code shown in the articles previous posted no longer seem to work as intended. If anyone can explain in detail why my solution seems much more complicated than those posted in the articles I linked to earlier, I would certainly love to learn.

Cheers.

-Braden

Comment: The "exception" in the diagram refers to tokenizer exceptions in `tokenizer.rules`, not `tokenizer.token_match`, which is checked before any other patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The default `token_match` for English is `None` (as of v2.3.0, now that the URL pattern is in `url_match`), so you can just overwrite it with your new pattern:

```py
import re
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
nlp.tokenizer.token_match = re.compile("^#\w+$").match
assert [t.text for t in nlp("#asdf1234")] == ["#asdf1234"]
```

Your example in the question ends up with the pattern `(None|#\w+)`, which isn't exactly what you want, but it seems to work fine for this given example with v2.3.5 and v3.0.5:

```
Token       Lemma       Stopword
========================================
2020        2020        False
ca      ca      True
n't     n't     True
get     get     True
any     any     True
worse       bad     False
#ihate2020      #ihate2020      False
@bestfriend     @bestfriend     False
<       <       False
https://t.co        https://t.co        False
>       >       False
```